# Retreiving the SOAP message context from inside the service endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, soap, interceptor

I have a spring boot application which expose SOAP web service using spring-boot-starter-web-services.

I'am getting the request's messageContext using EndpointInterceptor

```
@Component
public class GlobalEndpointInterceptor implements EndpointInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {

        //Here I get the messageContext
    }
}
```

In my service EndPoint I have :

```
@Endpoint
public class CountryEndpoint {

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "addCountryRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public AddCountryResponse addCountry(@RequestPayload AddCountryRequest request) {

        //Insert country and get the autogenerated ID

        //Insert the country ID along with the messageContext retreived from the intercepter. I can't get the messageContext here  !
    }
}
```

How can I retreive the message context inside my service endpoint

Comment: I suggest a read of [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/#server-atEndpoint-methods) which answers that question nicely. In short just add `MessageContext` as a method parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following to get the SOAP Envelope:

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "addCountryRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public AddCountryResponse addCountry(@RequestPayload AddCountryRequest request, MessageContext context) {

    //Insert country and get the autogenerated ID

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        messageContext.getRequest().writeTo(outputStream);
        String httpMessage = new String(outputStream.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(httpMessage);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you post sample example if you have?  I have done same but the request is not hitting to service